# for looping in sql developer

Tags: oracle, loops, oracle-sqldeveloper

Again there is a outrageously freaking error..

> not a single-group group function

I have got an empty table `mig_temp1`, which I want to fill with observations))
what is wrong about this select??

```
begin
  for j in 1..7 loop 
    for t in 0..32 loop
      insert into mig_temp1 (report_date, portfolio, bucket, Q)
      select add_months(to_date('31.10.2014','DD.MM.YYYY'),-t),
             cp.portfolio, j, count(*)
        from proba_cft pr, credtoportfolio cp
       where pr.credit_num = cp.credit and pr.dpd_47 between 30*(j-1)+1 and 30*j;
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: You select an aggregate; `count(*)` which returns *1* value as well as non-aggregates - `cp.portfolio, j` which return *n* values so you need a `GROUP BY` to define which groups of rows you wish to count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should work with a group by on `cp.portfolio`:

```
begin
  for j in 1..7 loop 
    for t in 0..32 loop
      insert into mig_temp1 (report_date, portfolio, bucket, Q)
      select add_months(to_date('31.10.2014','DD.MM.YYYY'),-t),
             cp.portfolio, j, count(*)
        from proba_cft pr, credtoportfolio cp
       where pr.credit_num = cp.credit and pr.dpd_47 between 30*(j-1)+1 and 30*j
       group by cp.portfolio;
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: can we use for like "for pid in (select pid from x_table)" and then further insert logic?